# Database design for billing triggers

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, postgresql, triggers

I am designing a database for a system where billing occurs at regular, custom intervals.  Because the intervals can be customized, I need to be able to process billing regularly, perhaps even daily.  I would like this to be a function of the database itself so that the interface doesn't need to manage this, which could be problematic.

I know that database triggers generally work off of DML statements.  Is there a way to create a trigger or automatic function in MySQL, PostgreSQL, or Oracle that would be able to process billing on a daily basis without using anything external to the database to trigger it besides system date?

Comment: Take a look at MySQL Events http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With oracle you would use the [dbms_scheduler package](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/DBMS_SCHEDULER)

For MySQL the [Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html) seems to do similar things (took this from Nicos comment)

There won't be a single solution which works for all these databases. If you need something cross platform, you might try a OS solution like [cron on unix](http://kb.iu.edu/data/afiz.html) or something based on some other language which is present on the system you develop. E.g. [Quartz Scheduler for Java](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)

Comment: For PostgreSQL there is [pgAgent](http://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgagent.php).  External, but tightly coupled / specific to pg.